# What's wrong with my twisted server that's supposed to take a .exe and send its stdio to anyone who asks. Instead, it doesn't send anything

Tags: python, windows-xp, twisted

```
print 'Preall test works!'
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.python import log
import sys
print 'Imports done'

class PrgShell(protocol.Protocol):
    data = ''
    class PrgProto(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
        def __init__(self, out):
            print 'Prgproto instance made'
            self.transportout = out.transport
            self.out = out
        def outReceived(self, data):
            """Called when process sends data. We send it on to transport, however if it's 'I want input', we need to activate input."""
            print 'Sub said: '+data
            if data == "input":
                print 'Sub wants input'
                self.transportout.write("input")
                sleep(0.01)
                self.transport(self.out.getWrit())
            else:
                self.transportout.write(data)



    def getWrit(self):
        print 'Proto gave input to prg'
        data = self.data
        self.data = ''
        return data 

    def connectionMade(self):
        global reactor
        print 'Connected'
        proto = self.PrgProto(self)
        addr = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\papa\\My Documents\\Python\\Files\\Maze\\exe\\maze.exe"
        reactor.spawnProcess(proto, addr)
        print 'Procces spawned!'


    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Data recived: '+data
        self.data+=data

print 'About to do stuff'
factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = PrgShell
#f = open("errors.txt", 'w')
#log.startLogging(f)
#print 'Logging started'
reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
print 'Runing'
reactor.run()
```

The program in question prints stuff first thing. When I connect to it, via raw sockets, it doesn't send anything. Here's the output:

```
Preall test works!
Imports done
About to do stuff
Runing (connect)
Connected
Prgproto instance made
Procces spawned!
```

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the executable print if run standalone? The twisted docs recommend you don't deal with stdout data until the process has ended, instead just write it all to a buffer and deal with it when your `PrgProto`'s `outConnectionLost` is called (you should implement `outConnectionLost`).

You should also implement `errReceived` for your `PrgProto` as this might help with tracking down what's going on.

If you aren't already, take a look at the full example on the [twisted process docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html#auto5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `reactor.spawnProcess(proto, addr)` with `reactor.spawnProcess(proto, addr, ['maze'], {})`.

Past experience has show that if you don't pass exe name as the first argument then nothing useful happens. However I have yet to find a reasonable explanation for why this happens.

Also you don't need `global reactor`. When you import the `reactor` you add it to the top level script namespace. This means that all functions and class in the same file can use it without declaring a global or importing again.

Also, you should not be using `sleep(0.01)` because:

1. Its not a builtin function. You need to import it from the `time` [module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep).
2. Twisted is a asynchronous framework where function should avoid blocking at all costs, and `time.sleep()` ([link](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep)) by its definition is a blocking call.

You should instead use `reactor.callLater()` [link](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTime.html#callLater) where you provide it will a callback and a time period. This will let twisted handle other things (like a new connection) while you wait.

Finally, you code at the moment would require the user to enter input before the program asks for any. This is because `getWrit` just sends stuff already in the buffer rather than asking the user. This means that if the user hasn't sent any data before `getWrit` is called then it will just return an empty string.

It would be a better idea if you used a deferred. Then what you would do is call `getWrit` which would immanently return a deferred and clear the data buffer. Then in `dataReceived` you would append data to the buffer until you got a newline character (`\n`). At which point you would call the deferred set up in `getWrit`.

Something like this:

```
print 'Preall test works!'
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.python import log
import sys
print 'Imports done'

class PrgShell(protocol.Protocol):
    data = ''
    class PrgProto(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
        def __init__(self, out):
            print 'Prgproto instance made'
            self.transportout = out.transport
            self.out = out
        def outReceived(self, data):
            """Called when process sends data. We send it on to transport, however if it's 'I want input', we need to activate input."""
            print 'Sub said: '+data
            if data == "input":
                print 'Sub wants input'
                self.transportout.write("input")
                d = self.out.getWrit() # getWrit returns a deferred. We store it in d to make the code more readable
                d.addCallback(self.sendInput) # Here we add self.sendInput to the callback chain.
                                              # This way self.sendInput gets called with the user input.
            else:
                self.transportout.write(data)

        def sendInput(self, data):
            self.transport.write(data)


    def getWrit(self):
        print 'Proto gave input to prg'
        self.deferred = defer.deferred()
        self.data = ''
        return self.deferred

    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'Connected'
        proto = self.PrgProto(self)
        addr = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\papa\\My Documents\\Python\\Files\\Maze\\exe\\maze.exe"
        reactor.spawnProcess(proto, addr, ['maze'], {})
        print 'Procces spawned!'


    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Data recived: '+data
        self.data+=data

        if self.data.endswith('\n'):
            if self.deferred:
                # We got a newline character, and there is a deferred to call, so lets call it
                d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None # This will set self.deferred to none to stop mistakes later

                d.callback(self.data) # Call the deferred with data. This will send the data to sendInput above.

                self.data = '' # Clear the buffer

print 'About to do stuff'
factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = PrgShell
#f = open("errors.txt", 'w')
#log.startLogging(f)
#print 'Logging started'
reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
print 'Runing'
reactor.run()
```